# c# multiplication operator that takes operands by reference

Tags: c#, matrix, reference, operators

I have struct type 4x4 matrices in a math library. They should remain structs (too many heap allocations otherwise, too much garbage).

There is a multiplication operator:

```
public static Matrix4d operator *(Matrix4d lhs, Matrix4d rhs) {...}
```

and there is a member function that takes the righthand matrix by ref:

```
public Matrix4d Mult(ref Matrix4d rhs) {...}
```

now, writing

```
Matrix4d DfromA = DfromC * CfromB * BfromA;
```

is much more readable than writing

```
Matrix4d DfromB = DfromC.Mult(ref CfromB);
Matrix4d DfromA = DfromB.Mult(ref BfromA);
```

Unfortunately the second version is twice as fast however.

Questions:

1. Why is the compiler not smart enough to take the arguments to the * operator implicitly by reference? Or treat value type arguments to methods generally by reference when their sizeof() is larger than a certain threshold?
2. Is there any way I can get the performance of the second option with the readability of the first one?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing built into the C# language as of yet.

There is a proposal for "readonly" parameters up on github:

> [#115:](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/115) Proposal: 'readonly' for Locals and Parameters

However, this has not (to my knowledge) been formally added to the roadmap, not does it explicitly say this will be possible for operators (though I suspect it would).

But right now, no, there isn't a way to get the `ref`-ness of the second solution with the syntax of the first.

If you're fine with unsafe code you can *sort of* get *some* of the behavior by making one of the parameters to the operator an address, but one of the operators will have to be the struct itself, which will be provided through memory copying, so it isn't all good.

Here's the code just for completeness *but I **strongly** advice against this!*

```
public static Matrix4d operator *(Matrix4d a, Matrix4d* b)
{
    return new Matrix4d(a.V00 * (*b).V00, ...);
}
```

You will have to call it like this:

```
Matrix4d c = a * &b;
```